# Getting recent transactions in a Site-based flow

Tags: yodlee

I'm using getItemSummariesForSite to gather account-level summary information using a Site-based flow and the REST API. I have a few questions about the transactions returned by this call and about querying transaction-level data in a Site-based flow.

1) Not all sites return transactions with getItemSummariesForSite. Is this determined by the container type or does it vary by Site?

2) How many transactions are returned when there are transactions from getItemSummariesForSite? Is it for a fixed number of days back or some other criteria?

3) Is there a way to force the returning of transactions and control how many transactions are returned (by how many days back, for example) OR to disable the returning of transactions entirely (as with DataExtent in getItemSummaryForItem1) when using getItemSummariesForSite?

4) If I want precise control of the transactions being queried (and to query them uniformly for all sites and container types) in a site-based flow (e.g. be sure that I get 7 days of transactions from the last time I downloaded transactions) is executeUserSearchRequest the right API call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would request you to please use the [executeUserSearchRequest](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/executeUserSearchRequest) API for getting transactions.

getItemSummariesForSite API is not the correct API for getting transactions.
Using executeUserSearchRequest you can control the date range for which you need transactions.

Comment: I'm using getItemSummariesForSite to get balances for all accounts and holdings for investment accounts. This API returns transactions for investment and card accounts (at least the ones I am testing) without me "asking for them". To be efficient, I wasn't going to hit executeUserSearchRequest for data already provided, but I can go ahead and do it anyway. Please let me know if I should use a different API for balances and holdings.

Comment: The executeUserSearchRequest API does not appear to return "commission" data for investment transactions. Is there a way to enable the returning of this level of detail?